# audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused when using sudo, what's wrong?

Tags: centos, ssh, sudo

i ssh to my remote centos sever as hugemeow, then i run sudo ls, then error happens:

```
[hugemeow@home ~]$ sudo ls
**audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused**
httpd
```

hugemeow is in /etc/sudoers, with the config as the follows:

```
hugemeow ALL=(ALL)     ALL
```

what's wrong with the msg showned above?

Comment: `rpm -qa| grep sudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing isn't important; it means that `sudo` is trying to connect to a local `auditd` server but that one isn't running.  You'll note that the `sudo` command worked anyway, despite the error.  This message should be suppressed in newer versions of `sudo` (according to Fedora bug [401201](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=401201), this was fixed back in 2010).

In theory, making sure that `auditd` is running on your system should make the error go away.